# Como selecionar texto entre espaços - REGEX?

Tags: javascript, regex

tenho uma string como essa de names:

```
var names = '    GEO  X   GEO3 X GEO4   X';
```

e eu preciso fazer um split utilizando regex para separar nos arrays somente os textos que estejam entre espaços e que não sejam X tentei assim:

```
console.log(names);

var re = /(^\s)($\s)/gi;
var nameList = names.split(re);

console.log(nameList);
```

mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente para isso, porecurei mas não achei nada :/ alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Seria bom ter um exemplo da saída esperada.

Comment: Esse `$` antes do `\s` me parece meio errado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar o método `.map()` com `.filter()` após o `.split` para retornar apenas os textos (considerando que os textos que você quer pegar estão separados por X). Nem precisa de regex, veja:

```js
var names = '    GEO  X   GEO3 X GEO4   X';

console.log(names);

var nameList = names.split("X").filter(function(e){
   return e;
}).map(function(e){
   return e.trim();
});

console.log(nameList);
```

### Edit

Pode ser que o X seja minúsculo em alguns casos, então seria necessário mesmo usar uma regex apenas para o `.split` para ignorar o *case sensitive*. No exemplo abaixo adicionei uns `x` extras para ilustração:

```js
var names = 'x    GExO  x   GEO3 X GEO4   X';

console.log(names);

var re = /\b[\sX]+\b/i;
var nameList = names.split(re).filter(function(e){
   return e;
}).map(function(e){
   return e.trim();
});

console.log(nameList);
```

**Obs.:** a regex usada é a mesma da [resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292419/8063).

Comment: Ficou ótimo! Realmente se o exemplo do autor for fiel ao problema real dele, essa é uma excelente maneira para resolver +1

Comment: Uma sugestão, se mudar `return e ? e : false;` para `return e;` provavelmente terá o mesmo efeito ;)

Comment: pq var re = re ?

Comment: @JulioHenrique Erro de digitação :D

Answer (score 5):

Com regex um exemplo simples seria usar `.split` com o meta-caractere `\b`:

```js
var names = '    GEO  X   GEO3 X GEO4   X';

var nameList = names.trim().split(/\b[\sX]+\b/i).filter(function (value) {
    return value;
});

console.log(nameList);
```

Como no exemplo do @dvd também usei o `trim`, mas usei previamente, já que `+` no regex já "elimina" os espaços entre as palavras e usei o `.filter`, sendo uma string vazia o `.filter` já irá considerar como `false` e irá filtrar ela o resultado que vem após o ultimo `X` de:

```
    GEO  X   GEO3 X GEO4   X
```

Que no caso seria mesmo uma string vazia.

---

### Explicando a regex

O `\b` é um meta-caractere que usado para encontrar uma correspondência no início ou no final de uma palavra, evitando assim que que palavras que tenham a letra `X` no meio sejam divididas também

Tudo que estiver dentro de `[` e `]` na regex serão considerados aceitáveis para dividir a string

O sinal de `+` é usado para que a expressão de regex anterior seja usada para casar com tudo que for correspondente, até encontrar algo que não "case".

> Detalhe importante, a `flag` `g` não é necessária quando usado com `.split`, então isso `.split(/\sx|x\s/gi)` terá o mesmo que `.split(/\sx|x\s/i)`

Comment: Valeu o toque lá do return. Realmente não era necessário.

Comment: Com *arrow function*, só pra encurtar: `names.trim().split(/\b[\sX]+\b/i).filter(i => i);` :)

Comment: @nunks dica legal!! Mas nem todos navegadores suportam ainda ES6, por isso não costumo usar em minhas respostas.

Comment: que que é o i mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: @JulioHenrique isto significa case-**i**nsensitive, é acaso queira separar o sua string via X ou x, se quiser apenas por X maiusculo remova ele.